# Android pdf links from TextView open in Google docs viewer

Tags: java, android, pdf

I'm stuck with this problem a couple of days. I'm making app which can read rss news generated by wordpress site. Some posts have a link to external pdf files, and I need to open those files from my app in Google docs viewer. I succesfully parses news in TextView and with Html(fromHtml...) and SetMovementh shows links which are clickable and fires browser. Problem is when link have .pdf files, they are downloaded but, as expected, cant be open by default. I need some method which can all links (href) ending with .pdf, from TextView,  open using Google docs viewer, for example:
... if url isEnding(.pdf) then open with GogleDocs else regular open url ...

```
public class ShowDetails extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.details);

        TextView detailsTitle = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.detailstitle);
        TextView detailsPubdate = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.detailspubdate);
        TextView detailsSadrzajPosta = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.detailssadrzaj_posta);
        TextView detailsLink = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.detailslink);

        Bundle bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();

        detailsTitle.setText(bundle.getString("keyTitle"));
        detailsPubdate.setText(bundle.getString("keyPubdate"));
        detailsSadrzajPosta.setText(Html.fromHtml(bundle.getString("keySadrzajPosta")));
        detailsSadrzajPosta.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());

    }

}
```

And my detail.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/detailstitle" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/detailspubdate" />
   <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/detailssadrzaj_posta"
        />

   <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:autoLink="web"
        android:id="@+id/detailslink" /> 

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

To view pdf in google doc viewer (copied from: https://www.b4x.com/android/forum/threads/intent-for-drive-pdf-viewer.53268/):

```
Private i As Intent

i.Initialize(i.ACTION_VIEW, "file:///" & File.DirDefaultExternal & "/myPDF.pdf")
i.SetComponent("com.google.android.apps.docs/com.google.android.apps.viewer.PdfViewerActivity")

StartActivity(i)
```

To override link behavior of `TextView`, you need to use `Spannable` and replace existing links (`URLSpan`) in TextView with your own `ClickableSpan`.  Or more simpler use library [Textoo](https://github.com/bluecabin/Textoo).

Combining the two, the solution would look something like:

```
TextView textViewWithLinks = Textoo
    .config((TextView) findViewById(R.id.my_text_view))
    .addLinksHandler(new LinksHandler() {
        @Override
        public boolean onClick(View view, String url) {
            if (url.endsWith(".pdf")) {
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                i.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.docs", "com.google.android.apps.viewer.PdfViewerActivity");
                startActivity(i);
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    })
    .apply();
```